# Is the symbolic link python important?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am on a Raspberry Pi, and by default the following symbolic links were created in /usr/bin:

> /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.7
>
> /usr/bin/python2 -> /usr/bin/python2.7
>
> /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.2

Most of my work is done in Python 3, so I decided to recreate `/usr/bin/python` to point to `/usr/bin/python3.2` instead. Does this have any negative consequences when I install packages or run pip? Are there utilities that depend on the alias `python` in the search path and end up doing the wrong things?

Comment: Is the question and your work about **development** using these tools, or about **using** these tools? If it is about development, please make it clear in your question. If it is about use, it may be better on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a good idea.  If you have a Python 2 version installed, then `python` should point to that.  See [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many applications and scripts that is written for python 2, and they usually come pre-installed in your linux distribution. Those applications expect `python` binary to be version `2`. And they will most likely break if you force them to run on python 3.

Answer (score 0):

According to the raspberry PI [docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/bashrc.md):

> In your home folder, you will find a hidden file called `.bashrc`
>   which contains some user configuration.

In that file, you can create an `alias` like this:

```
alias p="python3"
```

(Note there cannot be any spaces around the `=` sign).  Then you can run your programs with python3 by typing this:

```
$ p my_prog.py
```

Or you could set up your aliases like this:

```
alias p2="python2"
alias p3="python3"
```

which would allow you to run a program with python3 by writing this:

```
$ p3 my_prog.py
```

Who wants to have to type out the whole word `python`?